# focus the element and position after ui changes react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a list of data. I am showing this list as table. Each Item of list is row of the table.

```
class EditOrderItemField extends Component {
  render(){
    return (
   <div
      ref={(el) => {
         this.eachField = el;
      }}
    >
      {this.renderTagOrForm()}
   </div>
  );
  }
openForm() {
    console.log(this.eachField);
    this.setState({ edit: true }, () => {
        this.eachField.focus({preventScroll: false});
    });
}

    renderInputOrLabel(listItem) {
    const { edit } = this.state;
    this.save[listItem.key] = listItem.value;
    if (edit) {
        return (
            <Form
                onCancel={this.cancel}
                onChange={this.onChangeText}
            />
        );
    }
    return (
        <button
            className={'control-label'}
            onDoubleClick={() => this.openForm()}
            style={{
                position: 'absolute',
                top: 2,
                bottom: 2,
                left: 2,
                right: 2,
                cursor: 'pointer',
            }}
        >
            {listItem.value}
        </button>
    );
}

}
```

On doubleClick I am showing form. Form have more height than button. So even `pageYOffset(window.pageYOffset)` same after change in ui, I can not see my form.My form is at least 700px down in the page.

I want to see the form after change. For that I have created a reference and after  `setState`,  I focus that reference. `this.eachField.focus({preventScroll: false});`.

But This does not helped. What I can do in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess after introducing the new elements for edit it's increasing the table row height. That's why even of your pageYOffset is the same your actual content is being pushed down. So one easy solution would be to set the height for the table row upper limit. So that even after the edit elements appears relatively scroll position will remain same.

```
<tr style="height: 150px">YOUR ELEMENTS</tr>
```